# Finding a String in GTK Treeview

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

I'm using the TreeView Widget in GTK to show a list to the user.

```
        treeview1.AppendColumn (filename);
        filename.AddAttribute (cell, "text", 0);
        liststore = new ListStore (typeof(string));
        treeview1.Model = liststore;  

        foreach (var f in templist)
        {

                liststore.AppendValues (f);             

        }
```

How can I check if a string exists in the GTK Liststore before I add it?

Comment: Is sorting an option? The ListStore offers sorting, then it would be easier to find your duplicate. I assume that's what you mean by finding an existing one.

Comment: @oldtechaa Thanks... its not what I'm looking for .. actually i need to check if a string exists in the list.

Comment: Since [GtkListStore implements GtkTreeModel](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html#GtkListStore.description), could you just use [the GtkTreeModel functions](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModel.html)?

Comment: @oldtechaa uhm... im using C#... can you point me to an example...please

Comment: I have no idea about C#-specific documentation, but it's pretty simple, really. Since `ListStore` implements `TreeModel`, you should be able to call the `TreeModel` functions as though they were a part of your `ListStore`. If you can find `GtkTreeModel` in your favorite C# docs, and post it here, I'll try to explain it in C# terms.